# Discord Bot that gives roles on command doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord bot in Python that gives people roles on command. I tried this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '$attack':
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Do admin?')
        await member.add_roles(message.author, role)


client.run('MyToken!')
```

When I run the command $attack I get this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pandemicofnukes/PycharmProjects/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 271, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pandemicofnukes/PycharmProjects/bot/bot.py", line 31, in on_message
    await member.add_roles(message.author, role)
NameError: name 'member' is not defined
```

I don't have more ideas to get this working.

Comment: Remove the `await`?

Comment: thanks i will try it

Comment: Nope didn't work the bot did nothing...

Comment: Was there an error output?

Comment: no there wasn't any output

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: The latest one i think...

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).

`client.add_roles(message.author, role)` is returning `None` without being awaited.
It's impossible to determine why this is the case without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Well I tried to migrate and I had to add the reference "member" to `async def on_message` (see the new edit) and i get this new error (see edit).

Comment: The [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event handler is only passed a single `message` parameter.

Comment: But what happens when I take out the member parameter and put only the message parameter this error appears `File "/home/pandemicofnukes/PycharmProjects/bot/bot.py", line 31, in on_message
    await member.add_roles(message.author, role)
NameError: name 'member' is not defined`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Can you provide the full traceback? The only reason that error should occur is if your `on_message `event handler is called and it's expecting an extra `member` positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well problem resolved, I figured out...It was literally to add `from discord import Member` in `async def on_message(message):`

Thank you all for trying to help me!